Why don't they use lane 1 in track and field?
While watching the 400m race from the Paris Olympics, why do they use lanes 2-9 instead of 1-8?  I think there was one heat where they used lanes 1-9 because there were 9 runners.
So back to the initial question; why do they use lanes 2-9 by default?  Do they do this in college track and field or in the Track and Field World Championships too or is this something they only do for the Olympics?
UPDATE: Looks like the 200m was also like this too.

There can be multiple reasons for not using the inside lane of the track.
On the one hand, the inside lane is always used for the distance races, so that part of the track sees the most wear. To extend the lifetime of the track, race organisers (in particular at the lower levels) may opt to keep lane 1 free as much as possible in races run in lanes.
Another possible reason is that the inside lanes have a tighter bend than the outside lanes. At high speeds, like for the elite athletes participating in the Olympics, that tighter bend gives a slight disadvantage. This is factored in into how the lanes are drawn, but also in the decision to use lane 9 instead of lane 1.
For races without bends it is then just a matter of consistency to use a similar lane allocation strategy.
